# How to to count numbers in consecutive month in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning advance sql in oracle.
I want to find the count of numbers in two consecutive month . In  normal sql
my result could be produced like this way

```
select count(distinct number) 
from table1 
where date='1-sep-21' 
and number in (select distinct number 
               from table2 
               where date = '1-aug-21')
```

So these numbers from September are also found in August. What I want to get the result like

```
Month   count_number(current_month but also in previous month)
08-2021         122377 
09-2021          40000 
10-2021.          230
```

I am working in Oracle SQL. How can I achieve this? Kindly help me to get the idea.

Comment: Are you asking for each individual day of the months? As an example do you have a date value of **31-OCT-21** for **the first** table ..? eg I'm trying to understand if your first table has a date with day part not exists within the previous month such as **31-SEP-21** (*which is an invalid date*)

Comment: I tried really hard to read your mind but was unable to. Must have a bad day. So I couldn't figure out what your data looks like. You're showing what you did and what result you want but not the data you're running it against. This would be so much easier if you supplied some initial sample data in the form of scripts so we can recreate your dataset, understand it and give you a proper answer.

Comment: Please read and heed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Excression `in (select distinct... ` is working, however it slows down the query. Skip "distinct" keyword.

Comment: Either your description of the problem or your current query is wrong. You say "find the count" but in the code you write `count(distinct)`. If you need the count of **distinct** "numbers" then say so in the problem description, too. Then: From your attempt it seems that "the data" has the beginning of a month as the "date" - is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your WHERE clause has three problems:

```
where date='1-sep-21'
```

First, 'date' is a reserved word, so your column should not be named that.  Since you specified that in lower-case and without double-quotes, it would actually be considered case-insenstive and thus collide with the reserved word 'DATE', so I mus assume that is not really the name of the column.

Second, assuming your column is - *as it should be* - of type DATE, then you are comparing a DATE with the character string '1-sep-21'.  This will force an implied TO_DATE to convert that string to a DATE and may or may not throw an error, depending on the setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  Bottom line, you should never rely on implied conversions.

Third, you only specify 2 digits for the year of your 'date'.  C'mon, man.  In 1998-1999, I and millions of my colleagues spent way too much of our time remediating Y2k.  And now you try to recreate the problem.

Comment: ...and to think that the guy passed beginning SQL and intermediate SQL and is now learning advance[d] SQL...

Comment: Also, `in (select distinct ...)` doesn't need the `distinct`. (The optimiser will ignore it anyway.) So I make that 4 issues in a 6 line query.

Comment: `number` is also a reserved word, so that's 5 issues (7 if you count multiple uses), 8 if you count multiple uses 9f `date`! @WilliamRobertson